# Google Drive Realtime API SDK for Node.js or Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, node.js, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

What's the status of the Drive Realtime API library for Node.js or Objective-C? Am I correct that the only supported use case is client side in a browser (judging by the docs)?

I spent two days trying to get it working with a Mac app, no success yet. And I'm asking specifically about the Realtime API, because I got Drive APIs working fine.

Thanks for some feedback, I really couldn't find much on my own.

Comment: the docs say only client-side js is supported.

Comment: Yup, I know, that's the point of my question - whether there's a server js (Node) or Objective-C library coming.

Comment: thats my point. the docs clearly say its javascript. why do you think there would be an undocumented way to use it.

Comment: Beta version of a Node or Objective-C SDK, for instance. This question is asking whether anybody knows about anything new coming in that space or whether there aren't other ways of doing this. Of course I read the documentation (which I mentioned in the question). I read everything I could find on this, but I still have this question. And I know engineers from the Drive team are watching the tag 'google-drive-realtime-api', that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Plus 'javascript' is ambiguous - this only runs in browsers, I tried hacking it to run in Node instead but couldn't get that to work properly. If it worked with Node, I could just run a local server. But it doesn't seem like it does - thus my question whether anyone knows the status of the API running in different environments.

Answer (score 1):

The realtime api only runs from client-side javascript.
it does not run on a different environment even if the docs dont specifically say "from a browser". there are many places where the api docs talk about browser specific things like "client side oauth2 flow" or notes about Internet explorer etc. even the home page of the api says "javascript. no servers" which clearly implies client-side javascript.
Yes, maybe the docs should specifically say so instead of hinting it.
Maybe from your server you can load a browser object and pretend to be a client browser. There are libraries that do that. But you will have to deal with faking the oauth flow and such.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried hacking something like this, but before I'd invest a lot of my free time into this, I wanted to ask whether there isn't like a pre-release Node.js or Objective-C library. Or maybe someone has done this so they could give me a hint.
Plus the Google Docs iOS app does live collaboration and I assume they're using their own Realtime API, so it has been done before. Unfortunately, even though Google is "open", there's no info on how to do that from an iOS app. I really hope someone from the Drive team can just point me in the right direction.